# Whats the easiest way to declare 52 image icons in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an imageicon array whats an easier way of declaring them than just declaring each individual image.
ImageArray[0] = new ImageIcon("resources/images/cards/6.png");

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the images are 0.png through 51.png in the resources.images/cards folder:

```
ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[52]
for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
  images[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/images/cards/"+i+".png");
  }
```

Comment: How would you set that to a JLabel?

Answer (score 0):

Two most common ways:

- In a cycle - name your icons 1.png, 2.png and so on, then iterate using a temporary variable instead of a name
- Recursively read the directory content, adding all images into an `ArrayList`, then (if needed) call `toArray()`

Comment: how would i do the 2nd option?

Comment: Using `java.io.File` and it's method `listFiles()` in a recursive function. You can also apply a filename filter to grab only images.