# Image icon arrays

Tags: java

```
// Load the array of images
for(int i=0;i<52;i++){
    ImageArray[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/images/cards/"+i+".gif");
}

picture.setIcon(ImageArray[]);
```

What do I place between the `[]`?

i cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Why did you change the code from the advice you received in your other question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684489/whats-the-easiest-way-to-declare-52-image-icons-in-an-array) Use proper variable names. The first character of a variable name should not be upper cased.

Comment: The question in this posting was about solving your compilation problem. That answer was given by Serhiy so that is the answer that should be accepted. He also answered your many of your follow up questions. random problem. I suspect he won't be helping much in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously `i` cannot be resolver to type because it was declared within `for` loop. Put some number from 0 to 51.

```
picture.setIcon(ImageArray[0]);
```

Comment: But it will always be the same not randomized

Comment: Explain little bit better what you want to do ;) If you want it random, then use something like: `int pic_number = new Random().nextInt(52); picture.setIcon(ImageArray[pic_number]);`

Comment: If i do that is there a chance that the same picture will come up twice? and thanks

Comment: Yes there is a chance, very small bug there is. Check this http://www.cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html, it explains with exmaples how random in java works

Comment: Try it and find out. You learn by trying. Also, its about time you start accepting some of you answers if you want help in the future.

Comment: +1, for taking the time to respond to multiple question of the poster.